# What should I do before pushing application to GitHub when using CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, github, publish

this is my first time to publish my application using CodeIgniter. 
I used to push applications using SpringBoot or Scala to GitHub. At that time there were only files which I developed, and library dependencies ware written in `build.gradle` and `build.sbt`.

At this time, I am using CodeIgniter and there are a lot of files that have nothing to do with my application. Should I erase such files or publish my application without doing anything?? Or, is there something to do before pushing it to GitHub??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you you mean with "files that have nothing to to with my application"? Is it the codeigniter framework itself. I would personally commit all those, because you will need them again to ever restore your framework back its previous state.

If you mean external libraries such as those installed via composer or bower or something similar, I would leave those out of the repository. The libraries can always be re-installed from source later. And what's more, if external libraries are updated you don't want to have to keep updating your repository every time and fill it with unnecessary commits.

If you mean CodeIgniter's working cache, absolutely leave it out. These files will cause you problems if you ever pull your repository again, and they change constantly anyway.

Comment: @BenHiller thanks for reply!  Yes, I meant CodeIgniter framework itself. Come to think of it, it's weird to erase those files. I thought they are too many files but it usually happens!